# How to specify model in AngularJS custom directives?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-directive

I want to generate the following code using an AngularJS custom directive:

```
<body ng-app="">
    <label>Number 1: <input type="number" ng-model="a2"/></label> +<br/>
    <label>Number 2: <input type="number" ng-model="b2"/></label> =<br/>
    <hr/>
    <span>Total: {{a2+b2}}</span>
</body>
```

Therefore, I wrote the following code:

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('my-total', []);
    app.directive('myNumber', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                myLabel: '=',                        
                ngModel: '=',                        
            },
            template: '<label>{{myLabel}}: <input type="number" value="{{ngModel}}"/></label>',
        }
    });
</script>
<body ng-app="my-total">
    <my-number my-label="'Number 1'" ng-model="a1"/></my-number> +<br/>
    <my-number my-label="'Number 2'" ng-model="b1"/></my-number> =<br/>
    <hr/>
    <span>Total: {{a1+b1}}</span>
</body>
```

When the user types the numbers, the total is not shown.

How can I make it work? I mean, how can I pass the model variables "a1" and "b1" out of the directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make change to your `input` field inside your template, it should use `ng-model="ngModel"` instead of `value="{{ngModel}}"`

```
app.directive('myNumber', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            myLabel: '=',                        
            ngModel: '=',                        
        },
        template: '<label>{{myLabel}}: '+
                      '<input type="number" ng-model="ngModel"/>'+ //<-- change here
                   '</label>',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please find working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bateast/RJmhB/1/) for the same.

```
angular.module('test', [])
.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },
        template: '<label>Enter value: '+
                  '<input type="number" ng-model="ngModel"/>'+
               '</label>',            
    };
});
```